# how to implement hash map in java script?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am trying to implement simple hash map with key - value pair similar to java in javascript. 
I want to map index and corresponding page number, index as key and pagenumber as value.

for example -->  index - 1 , pagenumber-10

How to implement this in java script?

Comment: Just use JS Object. e.g. `a = {}`, `a['index']=1`, `a['pagenumber']=10`. The example is just one way you can do this. There are at least 2 other ways to declare JS Object and assign attribute to it.

Comment: how to this dynamically. I need to add the index and corresponding pagenumbers ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your question, but you can just do: a[1] = 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use javascript objects, where you can have key - value parametres,
e.g, : x = { index : 1, pagenumber : 10 }

you can have objects inside the objects, for example :

```
x = { a : { index : 1, pagenumber : 10}, b : { chapter : 1, pagenumber : 20 } }
```

and you can access this like below :

```
   x.a.index which gives you 1
   x.a.pagenumber which gives you 10
```

Comment: is it possible to add key value pairs dynamically into this object. similar to put functionality of java hash map? Answer works fine if we know the actual number of elements.

Comment: @user1103504 sure you can you do that. x['c'] = { "something" : "value"}